# while no me funciona correctamente al ponerle un if else dentro

Tags: c, condiciones, while, else

mi idea es hacer un programa que pida una contraseña, si la contraseña es correcta quiero que siga, y si es incorrecta quiero que vuelva a preguntarla.

esto es lo que se me ocurrió:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    
    int contrasena;
    int je = 1;
    
    
    while(je = 1)
    {
        printf("Ingrese la contrasena \n");
        scanf("%d",&contrasena);
        
        if(contrasena = 5589)
        {
            printf("contrasena correcta \n");
            je = 2;
            
        }
        else
        {
            printf("contrasena incorrecta \n");
            je = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

el error que tengo es que sea o no correcta la contraseña el while hace el ciclo nuevamente.

pd:disculpen si es muy basico :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El operador de comparación es el doble igual `==`. Lo que estás haciendo en tu código es asignar valores, no compararlos.

En [c](/questions/tagged/c) cualquier valor numérico diferente a cero, se considera `true`, así que `while(je = 1)` y `if(contrasena = 5589)` **SIEMPRE** se cumplen.